# VARCHAR(1) equivalent in C# land, SQL INSERT ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building a Web API that will be inserting some values into a Microsoft SQL Server database.

This APIs eventual usage will be in a JAVA Spring application.

I don't want to put the "carriage before the horse," so as a POC, I wanted to prove to myself first that I can call my Web API from a simple web page.

Essentially, my simple web page has some text input fields and when I click on a button, I validate the text fields and then create a JSON string out of them. Next I have an Ajax call that passes this JSON string to my controller. My controller in .NET land receives my request, but chokes with the following error -

> *An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"String or binary data would be truncated.*

And the stack trace follows.

> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError... blah blah

I think the problem is with several of the columns that I am attempting to insert into.

They are of type `VARCHAR(1)` and have the `NOT NULL` property in SQL Server.

On my simple web page, I never created a text input for these values. Instead, I figured that I could stick those values in when I am doing the actual `INSERT` on the server.  Incidentally, I am using the `TableAdapter` to handle all my database connections, etc...

Code that makes all this happen is as follows:

```
//JQUERY - collecting the input and generating the JSON
$('#pythonIsActive').is(':checked') ? activeCourse = 'Y' : activeCourse = 'N';  
        $('#pythonRequiresSecurityClearance').is(':checked') ? clearanceRequired = 'Y' : clearanceRequired = 'N';
        $('#pythonOfferedFall').is(':checked') ? fall = 'Y' : fall = 'N';
        $('#pythonOfferedWinter').is(':checked') ? winter = 'Y' : winter = 'N';
        $('#pythonOfferedSpring').is(':checked') ? spring = 'Y' : spring = 'N';
        $('#pythonOfferedSummer').is(':checked') ? summer = 'Y' : summer = 'N';
        $('#pythonIsTentative').is(':checked') ? tenativeCourse = 'Y' : tenativeCourse = 'N';

        var Course = {
            CourseID: $('#pythonCourseId').val(),
            CourseLongName: $('#pythonLongName').val(),
            IsActiveCourse: activeCourse,
            Description: $('#pythonCourseDescription').val(),
            DepartmentID: $('#pythonDepartmentId').val(),
            LabHours: $('#pythonLabHours').val(),
            LectureHours: $('#pythonLectureHours').val(),
            CourseShortName: $('#pythonShortName').val(),
            EffectiveYear: $('#pythonEffectiveYear').val(),
            EffectiveQuarter: $('#pythonEffectiveQuarter').val(),
            IsClearanceRequired: $('#pythonRequiresSecurityClearance').val(),
            ClearanceRequired: $('#pythonSecurityClearanceRequired').val(),
            CourseCoordinatorID: $('#pythonCoordinatorID').val(),
            IsOfferedQ1: fall,
            IsOfferedQ2: winter,
            IsOfferedQ3: spring,
            IsOfferedQ4: summer,
            Prerequisite1: $('#pythonPrerequisite1').val(),
            Prerequisite2: $('#pythonPrerequisite2').val(),
            Prerequisite3: $('#pythonPrerequisite3').val(),
            IsTentative: tenativeCourse,
            Prerequisites: $('#pythonPrerequisites').val()
        };
        courseDataToPost = JSON.stringify(Course);
        return courseDataToPost;
```

Next, I will pass this JSON String to my AJAX CALL like so -

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/courses",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    async: true,
    data: dataToPost,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
      alert("Success!");
    },
    error: function (x, e) {
      alert("The call to the server side FAILED. " + x.responseText);
    }
});
```

So, this successfully routes the request to the correct controller's method here -

```
    // POST /api/courses
    [HttpPost]
    public void Post(pythonCourse course)
    {
        var postTableAdapter = new tnpCourseTableAdapter();
        decimal zero = 0;
        string no = "N";

        try
        {
            postTableAdapter.Insert(course.CourseID, course.CourseLongName, 
                                    course.IsActiveCourse, course.Description,
                                    course.DepartmentID, course.LabHours, 
                                    course.LectureHours, course.CourseShortName,
                                    course.EffectiveYear, course.EffectiveQuarter, 
                                    course.IsClearanceRequired,
                                    course.ClearanceRequired, 
                                    course.CourseCoordinatorID, course.IsOfferedQ1,
                                    course.IsOfferedQ2, course.IsOfferedQ3, 
                                    course.IsOfferedQ4, course.Prerequisite1,
                                    course.Prerequisite2, course.Prerequisite3, 
                                    course.IsTentative, zero, zero, null,
                                    no, no, no, null, null, null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }            
    }
```

When I arrive here in the server code, the debugger stops on the catch block and gives the "String or binary data..." error.

Notice in my list of arguments that I pass 3 instances of the string `no`.

These arguments are strings, but SQL Server is expecting `VARCHAR(1)`.

Is this what is causing my grief, or is there something else going on?

Comment: Side note: `varchar(1)` is pointless - if you only have a single character - just use `char(1)` - it will use 1 byte of storage - always. `varchar(1)` on the other hand will use between 2 and 3 bytes of storage - depending on whether you have something in the column - or not. This due to the overhead of a variable length character column. For strings shorter than 5-10 characters - use `char(n)` - much better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means you're putting too much data into the column. Your column expects a single character string.

So the error means if you put `no` into the column.. it will be truncated to `n`.

Another example: If the column was `VARCHAR(5)` and you inserted "Hello World!", it would warn that it can only insert "Hello".

Comment: You may need to convert the string on its way in, since `varchar` is 8-bit .. whereas `nvarchar` would be sufficient. So I would advise changing the column to `nvarchar` if at all possible. If not, you'll have to convert your string to a byte array before inserting.

Comment: It may or may not be a single byte though. `varchar` expects it in a specific encoding (UCS-2 I think?). By providing SQL with a UTF-16 string from C# you're causing it problems. Changing the column to `nvarchar` would fix the issue.

Comment: Right, I agree with that. It must be because the one character string I have is greater than a single byte.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - ADO.Net will take care of any required translation of .NET types to their equivalent SQL types. If you find yourself "convert(ing) your string to a byte array before inserting", you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I disagree. While it is nice to rely on something to do something for you that kind of attitude will get you into trouble. It's better to match your output with the expectant input properties as best as possible.

Comment: Per Simon Whitehead's recommendation, I changed my STORED PROCEDURES to implicitly cast my one character values ("N") as a char instead of a string.  Also, changed everything else in the class to reflect this, like the member variables etc... to char.  This fixed the problem.  THANK YOU Simon!

Comment: Lesson learned here:  If you are writing to the DB from C# and you have a value on the DB that is VARCHAR(1), it's counterpart in .NET land should be a char, NOT a STRING!

Comment: @ivan_drago - or, you know, just a string containing a single character. That was the actual issue - you were trying to fit a quart into a pint pot. And my attitude doesn't get me in trouble. I rely on libraries that competent developers have spent thousands of hours working on to do the heavy lifting and understand the intricacies of talking to databases (ADO.Net) and concentrate on the problem areas that *I'm* an expert in.